# Object key as variable in handlebars (enduro.js)

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache, enduro.js

I'm trying to create **multilingual page using enduro.js with handlebars**.

I have created *objects* like:

```
{
  text: {
    eng: 'some text in english',
    ger: 'some text in german',
  }
}
```

and it works if I use it like this:

```
<h1>{{lookup text 'eng'}}</h1>
```

But want to select language using variable instead of static string, like:

```
<script> var selectedLanguage = 'eng' </script>

<h1>{{lookup text selectedLanguage}}</h1>
```

and its not working :(

**Any ideas how to make this work ? 
Maybe there is any different way to make it ?**

Comment: Ok, that was silly question actually. If someone has the same problem, answer is here: https://www.endurojs.com/docs/multilingual-support